# Is there a way to schedule job on heroku every 5 hours (or period that doesn't sum up to 24 hours)?

Tags: heroku, scheduler

I know there is a [free scheduler add-on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) in Heroku. The problem is that it only provides daily, hourly and every 10 mins. If it is every 4 hours, I can set 6 daily tasks. However, if I want a period that doesn't sum up to 24 hours, for example, 5 hours, seems there is no obvious option on the UI. Is there a way I can set the scheduler to start a job every 5 hours?